# outlook vsto sending mail

Tags: outlook, vsto, send, ribbon

I've been struggling with this for a while now and I can't get an answer anywhere.

I made an outlook add in which has a ribbon and two buttons, The one button opens up a mailitem where you can compose your mail and then the 2nd button sends the mail.

In the background it takes all of the recipients and adds it to the bcc field and sends the mail in batches for instance if there are 100 recipients it will send to 25 people at time.

So my problem is that it works perfectly on the developer PC but the send button doesn't work on the end user PC. The add in loads registries are fine and it targets the right .Net framework everything!

```
 private void CreateEmailItem(Outlook.Recipient strRecipientAddressTo)
        {
            string strFilePath = @"c:\temp\OutlookAttachments";
            string[] strFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strFilePath);
            bool bFileExists = Directory.Exists(strFilePath);
            Outlook.MailItem eMail = (Outlook.MailItem)
                        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            eMail.Subject = mailItem.Subject;
            eMail.BCC = mailItem.To;
            eMail.Body = mailItem.Body;
            if (bFileExists)
            {
                foreach (string file in strFiles)
                {
                    File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
                    eMail.Attachments.Add(file);
                }
            }
            ((Outlook._MailItem)eMail).Send();
        }
```

When the send button on the ribbon is clicked this method is called, but on end user the button just doensn't fire .. can this be permissions ? or any advice would be very much appreciated !!!!

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to suggest there but did you add any logging there. There can be chances that you are getting some crash in following line..
 email.Attachments.Add(file)
And thats why it is not reaching until send statement. You can check the event logs on user's system as well. They might help you.